# How to get specific id from for loop in django template?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working with django and javascript, I'm trying to follow and unfollow multiple users without refreshing the page. therefore i'm using ajax. The problem which i'm facing right now is that the first follower is getting follow and unfollow no matter if i click on that user or on other user.. its an obvious behavior because i couldn't understand how to get specific id of user from the for loop so that i can use that user in a js function.

```
               {% if follower.user in request.user.userprofile.follower.all %}
                 <span><a class="btn btn-success" id="follow-button{{follow.id}}" toggle="{{follower}}" type="submit">{% csrf_token %}UnFollow</a></span>
                 {% else %}
                
                 <span><a class="btn btn-warning" id="follow-button{{follow.id}}" toggle="{{follower}}" type="submit">{% csrf_token %}Follow</a></span>
                  {% endif %}
                </div><!--/ followers-body -->
                {% endfor %} 




<script>
    
        
        
        $(document).on('click','a[id^=follow-button]', function (e) {
            var user = $('#follow-button').attr('toggle'); //this user is coming the first use of looping object..no matter if i click on the 2nd or 3rd user of the loop.
            console.log(user,'im im im tested');
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url "profiles:toggle" %}',
            data: {
                user_toggle: user,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                action: 'POST',
            },
            success: function (json) {
                result = json['result']
                console.log(result,"maii mai maima maima a")
                if (result) {
                    document.getElementById("is_following").innerHTML = '<a class="btn btn-success" id="follow-button" toggle="{{user.userprofile}}" type="submit">{% csrf_token %}UnFollow</a>'
                    }
                else
                    document.getElementById("is_following").innerHTML = '<a class="btn btn-warning" id="follow-button" toggle="{{user.userprofile}}" type="submit">{% csrf_token %}Follow</a>'
                    
            },
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            }
            });
        })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more of JS/JQuery question than a Django one, but here is what I think you are missing.

When you add a listener to an element, you have an option to get the element that was interacted with using the saved word `this`.

Your problem in the code is that line where you retrieve `user`. If you replace `$('#follow-button')` with `$(this)` then you will get the user that was clicked.
From there you can retrieve the id easily.